# Python: Limit number of process calls by os.system

Tags: python, command, xterm

I need to run programs parallel, 3 at a time. I tried the following but when programC finished before A and B, it does not work. How can I limit the number of running programs to, say, at most 3 at any time.

```
for i in range(10):
     os.system("xterm -e program " + i + "a" + " &")
     os.system("xterm -e program " + i + "b" + " &") 
     os.system("xterm -e program " + i + "c" + " ")
```

Comment: You probably don't use `system` as you lose control over the backgrounded processes.  You probably need to use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my solution, though I will select a better answer:

```
for i in range(10):
    a = subprocess.Popen(["xterm -e program"+ i + " a" ],shell=True)
    b = subprocess.Popen(["xterm","-e","program",i," b"])
    c = subprocess.Popen(["xterm","-e","program",i," c"])
    a.wait()
    b.wait()
    c.wait()
```